# ANDROID_HOME is not set ... but its set perfectly?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ubuntu-14.04

I'm pretty much at my wits end here. I'm trying to run `ionic build` but its giving me this error:

```
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH.
```

`ANDROID_HOME, ANDROID_TOOLS, ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS` are all set correctly. Running `android` opens up the android sdk - I managed to add the android platform but why won't it do a build?

Comment: You may forget to set `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` and `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in manifest

Comment: Are you running windows or MAC?

Comment: is it ANT problem? I dont think so its about android path.